# avoiding redundant code in boost::variant visitors

Tags: c++, boost, boost-variant, apply-visitor

I am facing the following problem:
I have some visitors on for boost::variant, which all doing the same for a specific type, here foo, so the method

```
void operator()(const foo& ast)
{
    //allways the same
}
```

is allways the same in every single visitor.
Since I dont want to write this redundant method in all the visitors, I tried to avoid this adding a common base class, which implements this method, to all the visitors.
Problem the method calls the visitor itself recursivly, like this:

```
void operator(const foo& ast)
{
    for(auto&& item : ast.members)
    {
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, item);
    }
}
```

and since all the other methods, which are matching for the members arent implemented in the base class, I get an compiler error, on this.
Now my question is, how can I get rid of my redundant code?

Here is an example on how the problem could look:

```
struct variant_one;
struct variant_two;
struct nil{};
typedef boost::variant<
    boost::spirit::x3::forward_ast<variant_one>, 
    boost::spirit::x3::forward_ast<variant_two>,
    nil
> example_variant;

struct variant_one {};
struct variant_two 
{
    std::vector<example_variant> members;
};


struct visitor_one : boost::static_visitor<void>
{
    void operator()(const variant_one& ast)
    {
        std::cout << "visitor_one detected var_one" << std::endl;
    }

    //this is the redundant method
    void operator()(const variant_two& ast)
    {
        std::cout << "visitor detected var_two, output members:" <<std::endl;
        for(auto&& member : ast.members)
        {
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, member);
        }
    }
}

struct visitor_two : boost::static_visitor<void>
{

    void operator()(const variant_one& ast)
    {
        std::cout << "visitor_one detected var_two" << std::endl;
    }

    //this is the redundant method
    void operator()(const variant_two& ast)
    {
        std::cout << "visitor detected var_two, output members:" <<std::endl;
        for(auto&& member : ast.members)
        {
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, member);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
template<typename Derived>
struct VisitorBase {
    void operator()(const foo& ast) {
        for(auto&& item : ast.members) {
            boost::apply_visitor(*static_cast<Derived*>(this), item);
        }
    }
};

struct VisitorA : VisitorBase<VisitorA> {
    void operator()(const ItemType& item) {
         // do stuff
    }
};
```

or if the types used in visitors are the same/known beforehand and virtual functions are fine:

```
struct VisitorBase {
    void operator()(const foo& ast) {
        for(auto&& item : ast.members) {
            boost::apply_visitor(*this, item);
        }
    }
    virtual void operator()(const ItemTypeA&) = 0;
    virtual void opetator()(const ItemTypeB&) = 0;
};

struct VisitorA : VisitorBase {
    void operator()(const ItemTypeA& item) {
         // do stuff
    }
    void operator()(const ItemTypeB& item) {
         // do stuff
    }
};
```

In the first example you might want to make sure that you don't accidentally instantiate the template with a non-derived type, for example with this:

```
static_assert(std::is_base_of<VisitorBase,Derived>::value, "Derived should be derived from VisitorBase");
```

That will still leave open the possibility of instantiating a `VisitorBase`-derived type with a different `VisitorBase`-derived type in the template parameter, leading to undefined behavior. So be careful.

Comment: thank you very much, I think the first one should be fine, I would like to avoid virtual methods

Comment: @sehe As I undeerstood it, there are multiple visitor classes sharing the posted behavior for type `foo` but varying behvior for other types to `operator()`.